# Cannot create GeometryFactory : Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/geotools/geometry/jts/JTSFactoryFinder

Tags: java, geotools, jts

I'm having some trouble trying to create a Point and Polygon with JTS and GeoTools. I don't know what is causing the problem and I've tried everything but nothing worked for me.

If I compile the project with maven everything works fine, but when I'm executing it with Eclipse, when I try to create the Geometry Factory:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
```

It appears the next error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder from [Module "deployment.famaWebApp.war" from Service Module Loader]
```

It happens the same when using the constructor:

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();;
```

It shows the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory from [Module "deployment.famaWebApp.war" from Service Module Loader]
```

These are the imports:

```
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Polygon;
```

And this is the code:

```
// Patrón de expresión regular para encontrar pares de números entre corchetes
Matcher matcher;
// GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory();
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();
if ("Point".equals(geometryType))
{
    Pattern patternPoint = Pattern.compile("\\[([\\d.]+),\\s*([\\d.]+),\\s*([\\d.]+)\\]");
    matcher = patternPoint.matcher(coordinates);
    if (matcher.find())
    {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(2));

        Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(x, y));
        geometryFeature.put("coordinates", point);
    }
}
else
{
    Pattern patternPolyline = Pattern.compile("\\[\\s*([-+]?\\d+\\.\\d+),\\s*([-+]?\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s*\\]");
    matcher = patternPolyline.matcher(coordinates);

    // Buscar y crear objetos Point/Polygon
    int i = 0;
    Coordinate[] coords = new Coordinate[] {};
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(1));
        double y = Double.parseDouble(matcher.group(2));

        coords[i] = new Coordinate(x, y);
    }

    Polygon polygon = geometryFactory.createPolygon(coords);
    geometryFeature.put("coordinates", polygon);
}
```

The pom.xml is this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.locationtech.jts</groupId>
    <artifactId>jts-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.2</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
     <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
     <version>28.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
     <artifactId>gt-metadata</artifactId>
     <version>28.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know if I'm missing some dependencies or if I'm using the wrong version. In my project I'm using java 8.
I've tried to add gt-main dependencies and is still not working. Do you think of something that I'm doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: It sounds like eclipse is not picking up the jts jar - can you check it's on the project classpath? I think that is in build options tab

Comment: Hi Ian, thank you for your response. Yes, the jts jar is in the ./classpath of eclipse. The error appears when I execute the code, not in the compilation of the project. That's the wierd part.

Comment: How are you executing it? this would be using the SPI factory finding code which requires all the `META-INF/services` files to be combined some how - so it's possible that one of them is being overwritten by a later one

Comment: I'm running the application with Wildfly. I can't find the meta-inf/services directory. How i can know if one of them is being overwritten by a later one?

Comment: Do you drop in multiple jars or a single jar? See the bottom of the [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/build/faq.html)

Comment: Hi, I don't drop the project in any jar, I create a war. When I compile with maven I could use the maven plugin that is explained in the last question of the FAQ? Thank you again.

Comment: A correctly constructed war file should have no problem - are you sure it contains the jts jar?

Comment: Yes, all the jars are in the WEB-INF/lib, including the jts jar. When I compile it with maven it works fine. Is when i try to execute it with Eclipse that shows the error.

Comment: Then eclipse isn't picking up the jars in the WEB-INF/lib have you added that to your classpath?

Comment: I don't thick so. I tried to build a project only with the GeoTools and JTS libraries and there is working fine. Maybe in the project I have some libraries that are not compatible with this ones.